# how to make a basic app class with cordova in Android

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have an activity in cordova (see below) which was generated when I created the project. But now I need to create a java class that extends application and not CordovaActivity. This is what I got:

```
package com.guessSound.guessSound;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
// import com.parse.*;
// import com.parse.Parse;
// import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
// import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
// import com.parse.PushService;

public class GuessThisSound extends CordovaActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        // // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),3000);

        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

And I want to create a new class which is a application like below

```
package com.guessSound.guessSound;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
// import com.parse.*;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    private static MainApplication instance = new MainApplication();

    public MainApplication() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
      Parse.initialize(this, "xx", "xx");
      PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, GuessThisSound.class);
      PushService.subscribe(this, "Broadcast", GuessThisSound.class);
      ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

But when Im building the app, I receive the "cannot find symbol" for Application and Context. I have tried to import both Application and Context by writing import android.Context (the same for Application. So I figure that I need to use some sort of CordovaApplication since I extend the first class with CordovaActivity and not just Activity.

My androidManifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.3.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.guessSound.guessSound" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.guessSound.guessSound.MainApplication">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.guessSound.guessSound.GuessThisSound" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Facing the same issue with Parse at the moment with no apparent answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing a similar issue - also trying to create an Application class in order to get Parse Push Notifications not to crash with my Cordova project.

**Short Answer:** 
In your MainApplication file, you need to add an import 
`import android.app.Application;` 
and 
`import android.content.Context`

**Broader Question and Answer:** 
The larger problem we're trying to solve is to address the following error when using Parse Push Notifs with Cordova on Android: `java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library`.

The somewhat terse answer (provided at https://parse.com/questions/android-push-notification-error-msg) says that we should *"Create an Application class and register it in your AndroidManifest.xml. If you move your Parse.initialize into its onCreate method, your program will always call Parse.initialize before the service starts."*
This is where phonegap developers who have limited exposure to native Android development (like me) are left wondering what that mean.

Your implementation is the closest I've seen.
Another valid one can be found at 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/You$20must$20call$20Parse.initialize(context$2C$20applicationId$2C$20clientKey)$20before$20using$20the$20Parse$20library/parse-developers/AU31WlFG5yw/887uFopyOZAJ 

A good explanation of Android Application classes can be found here: 
 http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/ 

Note that I don't think you need a getContext method; so it seems your application class could be simplified to:

```
package com.guessSound.guessSound;

import android.app.Application;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Parse.initialize(this, "xx", "xx");
      PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, GuessThisSound.class);
      PushService.subscribe(this, "Broadcast", GuessThisSound.class);
      ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

The other important bit (which you've done) to get this working is to add `android:name="com.guessSound.guessSound.MainApplication"` to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.